# Thread Safe Method Invoke doesnt work

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, invoke

Sup Guys,

I Have a Function on my frmMain Class wich will update my control to something else after an invoke. When i type "?Label1.Text" on the Immediate Window, the text property IS updated, but when i go check the Form, nothing happened. The code is just like this

```
Public Sub UpdateUI()
    If (Me.InvokeRequired = True) Then
        Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf UpdateUI))
    End If
    Label1.Text = "ITS NOT WORKING =\"
End Sub
```

On my bgWorker Class:

```
Private threadUpd As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Updater)
Private _active as Boolean
Public Sub New()
    _active = True
    threadLimpar.IsBackground = True
    threadLimpar.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub Updater()
    Do
        If (_active = False) Then
            Try
                Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)
            Catch ex As ThreadInterruptedException
            End Try
        Else
            if(condition...) then
              frmMain.UpdateUI
        End if
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a classic trap in VB.NET, everyone falls into it at least once when they start using threads:

```
frmMain.UpdateUI
```

Now we can't see what exactly "frmMain" means.  But the fact that you posted this question suggests that frmMain is the name of your main form class.  Not the name of a field in your class that stores a reference to the main form.

That doesn't work.  The variable that the VB.NET compiler generates to allow you to reference as class as though it is a variable has `<ThreadStatic>` semantics.  In other words, every thread will create its own instance of a the form.  You can sorta see it when you write it like this:

```
frmMain.UpdateUI
frmMain.Show
```

But you'll see a "ghost" of the window, it is otherwise dead as a doornail since the thread it was created on is not pumping a message loop.

You'll need a real reference to the form.  That could be "Me" if Updater is a method of the form class.  If it isn't, Application.OpenForms could provide it.  Best thing to do is the give the class that contains Updater a reference to the form through its constructor.

Comment: I was almost sure it was something like this but can you give me an example how im referencing my already-opened form?

Answer (score 2):

You probably should terminate the function if InvokeRequired returns true, but you're setting the label text anyway. Here's what you might do:

```
Public Sub UpdateUI()
    If (Me.InvokeRequired = True) Then
        Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf UpdateUI))
    Else
        Label1.Text = "ITS NOT WORKING =\"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote just because you're performing equality comparisons between a boolean and a constant, but the OP's question did it so I'll +1 anyway. Use boolean operators.

Comment: Well I think I'm a dumbass cause this deffinitly does NOT work, altho, as i said, I can see it was updated if i check the Immediate Window, but the form itself got no update.

Any other hints

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following:

```
Public Sub UpdateUI()
    If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
        BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf UpdateUI))
    Else
        Label1.Text = "ITS NOT WORKING =\"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Still does not work, the label wasnt updated on the form, altho i can see it was "updated" thru the immediate window

Comment: Going on the code in your question, this solution should update the label text.

Comment: Well I think I'm a dumbass cause this deffinitly does NOT work, altho, as i said, I can see it was updated if i check the Immediate Window, but the form itself got no update. Any other hints?

Comment: What else is going on on the UI thread after kicking off this background thread?